# Preimage of a ball in a quotient metric space

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, quotient-spaces

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and define for each $x\in X$ and for $\varepsilon >0$ the ball $B_\varepsilon^X (x) := \{ y:y\in X \land d(x,y) < \varepsilon\}$. Now, consider a subset $A\subseteq X$ and define the quotient space $X/_\sim$ as $X/A := \{[x]: x\in X\}$ and with equivalence relation $x\sim y \Longleftrightarrow (x=y) \lor (x,y\in A)$; furthermore consider the surjective quotient map (projection) $\pi: X \twoheadrightarrow X/A, x\mapsto [x]$.

Now the questions:

1. Is there any canonical or "forced" induced quotient metric on $X/_\sim$?
2. How does $B_\varepsilon^{X/_\sim} ([x]) := \{ [y]: [y]\in X/_\sim \land d([x],[y]) < 
      \varepsilon \}$
3. How do I determine methodically $\pi^{-1}\big(B_\varepsilon^{X/_\sim} ([x])\big)$ for some $[x]\in X/_\sim$ ?

Comment: The quotient topological space in general is not Hausdorff. Even if it is metrizable, I do not think there is a natural metric on it.

Comment: There is a natural pseudo-metric on any $X/\sim$: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_space#Quotient_metric_spaces which under some conditions may be a metric. Another example is [Hausdorff distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_distance) which will generate a metric $X/A$ quotient if $A$ is compact.

Comment: @MoisheKohan I don't see OP requiring the metric to generate quotient topology. You are correct that this rarely can be done, but there are other interesting (pseudo)metrics on quotients.